# Record time consumed on every screen react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase analytics to analyse events for my application.

But I have a requirement to check(analyse) how much time a user spends on a screen.

Currently I used firebase event like this:

```
componentDidMount(){

        let randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000000) + 1);

        // console.log('random NUm ****** ',randomNum)

        firebaseApp.analytics().logEvent('Buy_Flow_Stage_1',{saleId: randomNum, trackingTime:Date.now()});
    }
```

So both the parameters display on firebase but how can I get the values, like I added a parameter `trackingTime: Date.now()`, then I am able to see the parameter but not its value.

[image]

Comment: are you looking for this https://datarockets.com/blog/session-recording-react-native-uxcam/

Comment: Not this one actually, I want to see how many users came to a particular event or screen along with the time they spend on that screen. for that I passed parameters for time and a unique id of that particular screen, problem is only with value. My parameters are visible on firebase console but not the value